# HTML: Accepting decimal number

Tags: jquery, html, numbers, decimal

The “total” text field sum up the numbers encoded but doesn’t sum up the decimal numbers or maybe doesn’t accept decimal numbers. This is my html code.

```html
 <th scope="col"><input type="text"  onblur="findTotal()" name="fil" id="fil" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="eng" id="eng" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="sci" id="sci" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="math" id="math" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="aralp" id="aralp" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="mapeh" id="mapeh" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="esp" id="esp" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="mtb" id="mtb" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="epp" id="epp" /></th>
              <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" /></th>


<script>
    function findTotal()
    {
        var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[name="fil"], [name="sci"], [name="eng"], [name="aralp"], [name="esp"], [name="mapeh"], [name="math"], [name="mtb"], [name="epp"] ');
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        }
            document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
    }
    </script>
```

This is the result...

[image]

Comment: You are passing them as Integer and expecting to add decimal values too? This will parse it as Int and add integer values only : `tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);`

Comment: Oh, that's why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting float value to integer will give unexpected results.

***Instead of `parseInt()`*** use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Working example:-

```js
function findTotal()
{
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[name="fil"], [name="sci"], [name="eng"], [name="aralp"], [name="esp"], [name="mapeh"], [name="math"], [name="mtb"], [name="epp"] ');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
    if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

```html
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text"  onblur="findTotal()" name="fil" id="fil" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="eng" id="eng" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="sci" id="sci" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="math" id="math" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="aralp" id="aralp" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="mapeh" id="mapeh" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="esp" id="esp" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="mtb" id="mtb" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="epp" id="epp" />
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" />
</th>
```

Comment: I didn't notice that one. This is great! I

Comment: @VenesseYoon  Glad to help you :):)

Comment: @Alive to Die No problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are using parseInt which converts the decimal values as int so it is getting integer result.Remove parseInt and in total add parseFloat Use code like:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal()
{
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[name="fil"], [name="sci"], [name="eng"], [name="aralp"], [name="esp"], [name="mapeh"], [name="math"], [name="mtb"], [name="epp"] ');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
    if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
    }
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
</script>
```

```js
function findTotal()
{
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[name="fil"], [name="sci"], [name="eng"], [name="aralp"], [name="esp"], [name="mapeh"], [name="math"], [name="mtb"], [name="epp"] ');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
    if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
    }
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

```html
<th scope="col"><input type="text"  onblur="findTotal()" name="fil" id="fil" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="eng" id="eng" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="sci" id="sci" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="math" id="math" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="aralp" id="aralp" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="mapeh" id="mapeh" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="esp" id="esp" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="mtb" id="mtb" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="epp" id="epp" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" /></th>
```

Comment: Your code adds zero before the number as the result. I just found a solution by using `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

Comment: @VenesseYoon. yes i update the code. in total use parseFloat but don't need to use parseInt in if

Comment: Okay. Better try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're casting to `int`.

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[name="fil"], [name="sci"], [name="eng"], [name="aralp"], [name="esp"], [name="mapeh"], [name="math"], [name="mtb"], [name="epp"] ');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    tot += Number(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">fil</th>
    <th scope="col">eng</th>
    <th scope="col">sci</th>
    <th scope="col">math</th>
    <th scope="col">aralp</th>
    <th scope="col">mapeh</th>
    <th scope="col">esp</th>
    <th scope="col">mtb</th>
    <th scope="col">epp</th>
    <th scope="col">total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="fil" id="fil" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="eng" id="eng" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="sci" id="sci" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="math" id="math" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="aralp" id="aralp" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="mapeh" id="mapeh" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="esp" id="esp" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="mtb" id="mtb" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" name="epp" id="epp" /></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" /></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**: My solution before using `arr.map().reduce()` did not work as the result of `document.querySelectorAll()` is a `NodeList` not an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `parseInt()` with [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to use decimal numbers instead of whole numbers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal()
{
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[name="fil"], [name="sci"], [name="eng"], [name="aralp"], [name="esp"], [name="mapeh"], [name="math"], [name="mtb"], [name="epp"] ');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
    if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
</script>
```